# Derivation of normal equation for linear regression parameters

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I'm going through a derivation of the normal equation for the parameter vector $\beta$ of the linear regression model. Given a model $y = X\beta + \epsilon$, where $y$ is the vector of dependent variables, $X$ is the matrix of explanatory variables, $\beta$ is indeed the vector of parameters and $e$ is the vector of the errors. Given $\epsilon = y - X\beta$, they set out to minimise the sum of squared errors, which can be written in vector form as $\langle \epsilon, \epsilon \rangle = \epsilon^T\epsilon$, namely:

$$ (y - X\beta)^T(y - X\beta) \\ = y^Ty - y^T(X\beta) - (X\beta)^Ty + (X\beta)^T(X\beta) \\ = y^Ty - (X\beta)^Ty - (X\beta)^Ty + (X\beta)^T(X\beta).$$

$(X\beta)^Ty$ is the transpose of $y^T(X\beta)$, so I'm wondering why they've taken the tranpose of the second term.

Comment: All the terms are scalars (which you can think of as $1 \times 1$ matrices), so in fact $(X\beta)^\top = y^\top (X \beta)$. There is no need to take the transpose of the second term, but maybe they felt it is nice to point out it is the same as the third term.

Comment: Ah because $X$ is n x 2 and $\beta$ is 2 x 1, so their product is n x 1, so if you multiply it by the $y$ vector which is either n x 1 or 1 x n (depending on whether you tranpose it or not) you indeed get a 1 x 1 result. I see, thanks.